# Adobe AIR app fit screen(maximize) by itself

Tags: air, fullscreen, maximize

Is there a way to make an Adobe AIR app
fit screen(maximize) by itself when it's
launched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Abhilash :

Just call the `maximize();` function in the Application creation
Complete function.

Source :
http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/browse_thread/thread/afd5a97aea768d52/59aabcf6a74171b9#59aabcf6a74171b9

Answer (score 1):

Add a creationComplete event to your application

```
   <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                           width="950" height="500"
                           showStatusBar="false"  
    creationComplete="winApp_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
```

Then Add the maximize(); function to the creation complete event.

```
protected function winApp_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{

maximize();

}
```